# How to remove hand-indexed C++ boilerplate brace-enclose lists?

Tags: c++, initializer-list, boilerplate

I have a derived class interface for which my base class needs to define the following three protected member arrays:

```cpp
template<size_t n> class Base{
public:
    static constexpr size_t n_ = n;
};

class BaseCat: protected Base<4>{
private:
    // define arrays conveniently here, using brace notation
    double A0[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; // this is the desired part
    double A1[] = {13,-2};
    // ...
protected:
    // the following three lines are the boilerplate
    double* A[] = {A0,A1,A2,A3}; // this is the undesired part
    double* x[] = {x0,x1,x2,x3};
    double* b[] = {b0,b1,b2,b3};
};

// the implementation of "Derived" requires A[],x[],b[] of length n to exist.
using DerivedCat = Derived<CatBase,CatBase::n_>;
```

This could be code written for each of the classes BaseDog:Base<3>, BaseCat:Base<4>, BaseMouse:Base<24>, and each time I hard-code some polyhedra in A,x,b for the respective model. A derived class ProcessedBase<BaseCat,BaseCat::n_> will need the protected members A,x,b to exist of according size n.

As far as I understand, macros cannot be used because of `n`, which is not necessarily always of value 4.

Template functions also cannot be used because A0,A1,... are hand-written variable names, hence they would have to be hand-written in the templated assignment function in turn, and would have to be passed to it, which is as much boilerplate as writing them into brace-enclosed lists.

Finally, one could try to force a mapping of names A0 to A[i] in a base of Base, but then the convenient definition of A0 via brace-enclosed list in the upper part is impossible.

Can I get the best of both worlds, i.e. keep the desired part while avoiding the undesired part as commented in the code?

Comment: unclear what code you want to get rid of. You want to declare arrays and initialize them with certain elements and thats just what `double* A[n] = {A0,A1,A2,A3};` does. You dont need the `n` though, `double* A[] = {A0,A1,A2,A3};`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I would like to get rid of the three lines after the comment "boilerplate". I write many Base Classes that use the same class template for a derived class. Each time, the derived class expects the arrays A,x,b. In my base class, I find it very convenient to define the members as A0=brace-enclosed list, etc. This is the part I like. What I want to get rid of is having to rewrite the latter three lines for each of my base classes. (some use n=4, others n=1, n=8, etc).

Comment: Why use pointers here? Are these actually constants?

Comment: @tadman They are not constant, but they have default values. They are also constant at the moment, but they are passed to non-const interfacing functions (that however _should_ not change their values).

Comment: So they're constant, but not. I mean, sure? The reason I'm asking is these could be `static const` if they're not necessarily bound to any individual instance.

Comment: what is `Base` actually? How are the derived classes going to use `A`,`x` and `b` ? Its difficult to know how to avoid writing the code when almost all we have is the code to be avoided. What comes to my mind first is that derived classes accessing `A0`,`A1` etc via `A[i]` does not actually require `A` to be an array of pointers or an array at all. Then I also dont understand why `A0`, `A1` etc must be seperate members rather than one 2d array

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai You _could_ make one array A_buffer and write all Ai into it contiguously, and then initilize A as list of pointers showing at the start of each Ai, as is done with csr sparse matrix types, for instance. But I like the fact that users can use brace-enclosed lists for each Ai separately. Maybe, from your proposal, it could be worth it to pass each Ai from a brace-enclosed list to a push_back function that writes them into A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
template <size_t n> class Base
{
public:
    static constexpr size_t n_ = n;
};

class BaseCat: protected Base <4>
{
protected:
    double A [n_] [10] =
    {
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
        { 13, -2 },
        { 14, -3 },
        { 15, -4 }
    };
    // x, b, ...
};
```

Which is pretty much what @463035818_is_not_an_ai said.

Note that this reserves more storage for `A` than is actually needed, but maybe that's not an issue for you.  And it's definitely time to think about making `A` `const` (or `static constexpr`).

Comment: I knew that this works, but it is so inefficient. The issue is that sometimes A0 is ten times larger than A1, etc. As I can see now, my question is exactly on this matter: Can we benefit from initializing each Ai with bracket-enclosed list while constructing A[] without boilerplate as a list of the Ai ?

Comment: Well, how much initialisation data do you have? Ten x zero = zero.

Comment: It is not doubles, but user-defined class objects. I just wanted a minimum example; but it is about memory efficiency and convenient initialization at the same time.

Comment: Can you make those use minimal memory if default initialised?

Comment: Ok, I see. So this is a good idea. Still I am surprised there is all this fanciness with brace-enclosed initializer lists, yet their _efficient_ utility is limited to 1D.

Comment: I guess that's just the way it is, initialising arrays in this way is inherited from C.  Feel free to accept, I don't see a better solution.

Comment: fine, although 1) I doubt that is the best one can do. E.g., making a macro for each possible n is already better. And 2) the question implied that this is not useful; ... or rather, I did ask the question despite it was to be assumed I knew the feasibility of grammar of your proposed answer, and still asked the question since discarding that sort of an answer preemptively.

Comment: @HKoplin you can use `std::vector` to trade dynamic allocation for less waste of memory